# Android Studio Profiler memory graph

Tags: android, android-studio, memory

I've updated Android Studio to the version 3. Instead of Android Monitor it includes Android Profiler now. In 2.3.3 Android Monitor shows that the app uses 5MB of memory, but Android Profiler in the version 3 shows that it uses 18MB. Same device, same app - significant difference. Which of these tools shows the memory usage correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When compared to memory counts from the previous Android Monitor tool, the new Memory Profiler records your memory differently, so it might seem like your memory use is now higher. The Memory Profiler monitors some extra categories that increase the total, but if you only care about the Java heap memory, then the "Java" number should be similar to the value from the previous tool.

also see here：https://developer.android.google.cn/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html